# Using blocks in NSOperation main method

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, nsoperation

I'm using blocks inside a `NSOperation`. The `main` method of my `NSOperation` looks like this:

```
- (void) main {

    [self callMethodOfALiraryUsingCompletionBlock:^() {
       //this method takes time to execute, will call this block when done
    }];
}
```

I'd like my `NSOperation`to terminate when what's inside the block is done. Currently, it returns directly, before what's inside the block is executed ... Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: You are calling a method that takes a block, so what is "callMethodWithBlock" doing?. Perhaps you should just write the code you want to execute in the main method?

Comment: How about using [NSBlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: Thx guys for your answers, I edited my question. The method called takes a long time, and I have no access to it since it's from a library. The block is just a "completion" block called when the method finished the job

Comment: There is no general solution to your problem.  There might be a solution specific to the library you're using, so stop making us play guessing games.  Tell us what library you're using, and show us the real code.

Comment: Since your question is so vague, I can only point you to Apple's guide to [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8).

Comment: You are not telling us anything useful. But I'd guess that you have some asynchronous processing going on which is why `main` returns so quickly. Refactor your `callMethodOfALibrary...` method so it is synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little detail in your question, here is one possible outline which may help:

- Create a semaphore (`dispatch_semaphore_create`)
- Execute your library code asynchronously (`dispatch_async`)
- Have the completion block for your library code signal the semaphore
- Have your main method wait on the semaphore

HTH